# Online WYSIWYG editor using a div

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, wysiwyg

I'm trying to create a WYSIWYG editor using a div, just like Google Docs works (as far as I know). I am aware there are other, easier solution for editors, but all have one thing in common: they output terrible HTML thanks to the Javascript execCommand() function. I really need it to output clean HTML (and the same HTML across browsers), so therefore I'm thinking about writing my own editor with a regular div and some Javascript (to record click and keypresses etc.) Before I do that though, I have a couple of questions:

- Does the editor I'm looking for (one that outputs the same, clean HTML across browsers) already exist?
- Am I mistaken that it is possible to write this?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: I think I should have been clearer on this: I don't consider existing WYSIWYG editors (like TinyMCE or CKEditor) an option, because (and please correct me if I'm wrong) they use the Javascript execCommand() function. This (especially in combination with an iFrame in design mode, which they both use), outputs different, illogical HTML in different browsers. For example: a simple enter in Safari causes it to create a div, instead of adding a `<br />` tag or create a new paragraph (`<p>`). Furthermore: making text bold causes Mozilla to add `<span style="font-weight: bold">`, Internet Explorer and Opera to add `<strong>` and Safari to add a `<b>` tag. Not to mention the tricks some browsers pull by adding their name to tags (Safari I'm looking at you, I don't like `<span class="Apple-style-span">`). Because there's no way to change all these strange behaviors, it's very hard for me to make the site look consistent.

That's the reason I'm thinking about writing my own alternative: cross-browser compatibility and consistency...

Comment: Either it exists or your mistaken. There is no WSISWYG to semantic HTML compiler.

Comment: I much prefer WYSIWYM to WYSIWYG.

Comment: I promise you, you're in for a world of hurt to go create this yourself. Save yourself 3 years of your life and use one that's already available. The answers surely have what you need.

Comment: **Raynos**: Could you please elaborate why it is impossible to create something that doesn't exist yet? **zzzzBov**: I think you're right, thanks for the hint! **Jordan**: Is it really that hard? Thus far the answers don't really have what I need, could you help me with this?

Comment: I don't know what you have tested, but the output problems that you mention doesn't exist in CKEditor because there's a lot of code added to take care of the different browsers and in fact, most of the formatting commands are done by CKEditor itself instead of relying on the problems with execCommand

Comment: And BTW, Google Docs doesn't use "just a div", it's a very complex editor (and it's able to do things that no other editor does), but you don't even want to look at the HTML that it uses, that's really horrible for a HTML purist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an editor from scratch is a massive undertaking because of the sheer number of browser quirks and bugs with in-browser editing. I've done it several times for various niche projects. My advice would be to start with either TinyMCE or CKEditor as a base and extend them. Both have had unbelievable amounts of development time poured into them over several iterations to get them as good as they are now. Try taking a look at their bug trackers to get an idea of what they have to contend with. Both have decent options for extension, so you could write your own formatting commands to replace `document.execCommand()` and in both you can add buttons/tools to the toolbar and context menus.

**Self-promotion alert:** Another option for the future is to use the commands module I'm working on for my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library. It's some way off completion but will initially have replacements for inline formatting commands offered by `document.execCommand()`, and will allow control of the tags/CSS it produces. Rough early demo here: http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1point2/demos/commands.html

Comment: Hi Tim! That looks great! It works almost perfect, but there's one small problem (I think). If you remove all text from the editor and type a couple of words, and then hit enter, it will not add the `<br />` tag. It will add a new `<div>` instead. Do you know how to fix this?

You don't have this problem if you're not using the iFrame in design mode or with a contenteditable tag... Thanks!

Comment: @Frog: If you're referring to the Rangy demo, that's only demoing bold and italic commands and I haven't done anything about pressing the Enter key. TinyMCE and CKEditor both have stuff to handle that though.

Comment: Tim: I'm aware of that, but I believe that problem occurs as soon as you use either use an iFrame in design mode or a contenteditable element. As far as I know there's no way to fix that (with or without Rangy), or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Frog: You can hack round it, although it's not that easy. Example: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/7140/_samples/enterkey.html

Comment: That's exactly what I needed Tim! It basically removes my need to create my own alternative (for now). Thanks a lot, I will accept your answer.

Comment: If you check other samples of CKEditor you'll see that you can control how the styles must be applied: b, strong or span class='bold' are all possible as it's working directly with the selection instead of calling execCommand

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this.  There are teams of developers behind high profile WYSIWYG editors, and they already have the workflow built into their development to handle cross browser testing.

Look at

- [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)
- [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)
- [Dojo Toolkit's `Dijit.Editor`](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/Editor)

Comment: Thanks for you response Michael! Please look at my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

1. http://280slides.com/  built for  the canvas tag
2. Everything is possible if you are stubborn enough.

Comment: Hi Aleksander. Thanks for the great answer, I especially like the second point. :) 280slides.com works great. However, I don't think I can go down that road, because canvas is not supported in many browsers as of now... I believe Google did this with just Javascript in their Docs application though, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

The two we looked at were:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

and

http://ckeditor.com/

Both did exactly what we wanted but in the end we went with the commercial CKeditor.

Comment: Hi kasdega. Thanks, but please take a look at my edited post. I think there are some problems with both.

Answer (score -1):

Did you already try [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) ?
You have full control over the output via different parameters or existing plugins, also possible to write your own plugin..

Comment: Thank you for the response! Yes, I did try that (I even use it in some projects), but I think there are some problems with it. Please look at my edited post.